# redirected you too many times error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, hosting

I have uploaded my Laravel project on Infinityfree free hosting.
My url is like this: http://abc.freecluster.eu/
But it shows ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I have added below code in .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.freecluster.eu/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: check if mod_rewrite works or not. and also check the code there is an infinite loop that calls itself.

Comment: i have added .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Check that your routes don't have the same name, otherwise they will just redirect you to each other causing this error. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435866/laravel-err-too-many-redirects) might be relevant.